# j2me running thread while device is in energy saving mode

Tags: multithreading, java-me, alarm

I have created an application which stores a set five different times, at each time i play an audio. I have done this using thread. But the audio does not play when the device is not in active mode. How can i play the audio despite the status of the mobile?
In android i have done this using alarm manager. Is there such an option in j2me?
Please help with code if you have the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i remember correctly, background operations are not possible in j2me, due to midlet lifecycle. If device is not active the application remains in pause-state.

Comment: Is there any work around for this? also if the time for playing is set for 1:00 pm, and i activate the device at say 1:10 pm, the audio plays at that time, which shouldn't be. how can i block that if there no work around for the first method?