# j2me draw images on form with lwuit

Tags: image, forms, java-me, lwuit

I'm using lwuit library.
i have a form with a background image.
and i want to place another image on top of it at a particular angle, and at a particular position(center for instance).
How can this be done. please help with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the image on the `Label` and place into the particular position on the `Form`. Use [`getStyle().setMargin(....)`](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/plaf/Style.html#setMargin%28int,%20int%29) for place the particular position on the `Form`.

Comment: thanks for the help, i was able to position the image, but how can i rotate or place the image at a particular angle?

Comment: If you want to rotate the image means use `image.rotate(degrees)`.

Comment: thanks it worked for me. Can please help on the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332576/j2me-running-thread-while-device-is-in-energy-saving-mode